# Pointers and casting in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, pointers, casting, endianness

I am very confused with this kind of casting. Can someone explain what exactly it is happening in this sentence?

```
x = *(char*)&n;
```

That is the complete code, and it is used to know if a machine is little endian or big endian.

```
 int n = 0x1234567;
 char x;
 x = *(char*)&n;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&n` takes the address of `n`, but crucially, it's the lowest-addressed byte of `n`.  `(char *)` tells the compiler to treat that address as a pointer to a `char`, i.e. a pointer to a single byte.  `*` dereferences that, i.e. it obtains the byte value stored at that address.

So the overall effect is that `x` is set to the value stored in the lowest-addressed byte of `n`.

Comment: ... which in the OP's example will be either `0x67` or `0x01` depending on endianness.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth Thank you for your help. So, wouldn't be the same to write: `x =(char)n;`

Comment: @Manolete - `x` will always be `0x67` if you do that.

Comment: @Manolete: no, that converts the entire value of `n` to a `char`, truncating it to `0x67`. Going through the `char` pointer gets you either the first or the last byte in the value.

Comment: @Manolete: No.  That would simply convert `n` to a `char` (effectively doing `n % 256`).  This would be invariant of endianness (i.e. you'd always get the same result).

Answer (score 4):

`&n` takes the address of `n`, which is the address of an integer.

`(char*)(&n)` reinterprets this information as the address of a `char`.

`*(char*)(&n)` dereferences this address, that is, it is the value of the `char` that lives at that address. In other words, it's the value of the first byte of the representation of the integer `n`.

Now you can check whether that's `0x01` or `0x67` to determine which way round your integer is stored.

As a side note: It is always permitted to reinterpret *any* valid address as the address of a char and inspect it, both in C and in C++. This is necessary whenever you want to perform I/O, since you can only input/output dumb *byte* streams, which you obtain in this fashion (that is, you can treat any `T x;` as a `char[sizeof(T)]` and access it via `(char*)&x`).

Comment: You said that it is legal to interpret any address as a `char*`. Is it also legal to dereference a pointer to any `T` that has been interpreted as a `char*`? That is, is `T x; char c = *(char*)&x;` always legal?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Yes, since every object has size at least 1.

Answer (score 3):

To help you visualize why this code can be used to detect the 'endiannes' of the environment.. In a big endian environment that uses 32bit ints the number will be stored in memory in this byte order

```
01 23 45 67
```

In a little endian environment it will be this order

```
67 45 23 01
```

If you forcibly cast an `int` pointer to an initialized int to a `char` pointer, the char pointer will be deferenced to the first byte of the int as it is stored in memory.

In a big endian environment this will deference to `01` and in a little endian environment it will be `67`.

If ints aren't 32 bits you'll get different values altogether.